# Cleaning before bedikas during clean days

Tags: halacha, niddah, personal-hygiene

Can a woman clean herself internally [a sufficiently long time, not immediately] prior to doing a bedika *during the seven clean days*?

[This page](http://www.yoatzot.org/questions-and-answers/answer.asp?id=1259) seems to say on the one hand

> [...] you may not clean yourself in this fashion after the hefsek
>   taharah, prior to performing the bedikot of the seven clean days. These bedikot are intended to confirm that you have remained clean
>   after the hefsek taharah and moch dachuk.

but on the other hand

> Cleaning oneself internally is permitted during the clean days, but should not be done immediately prior to a bedikah.

Is the first quote is referring to doing it immediately, while the second to some time [a few hours?] before?

Comment: Welcome to Mi Yodeya! Thank you for sharing the question!